# Force query results to paginate/divide large query into smaller ones to avoid timeout with crummy API

Tags: c#, database, pagination

I am using the provided Epicor Prophet 21 database API to form queries to our database. All is well until I form a query to return data on about 200 inventory parts at once. The 1 minute request TimeOut seems to be built into the assembly files, and there is no functionality for pagination or specific output selection.

I have thought about trying to divide the list alpha-numerically by the itemIDs, (eg. returning all itemIDs > GGGGGGG, then all itemIDs < GGGGGGG). But the IDs are all of different lengths, and the middle point shifts about. This seems clunky, and there must be a better way to divide the query results without knowing what the specific results will be. The API provides standard query filters: comparison operators =><, and/or, startsWith, endsWith, subStringOf.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not return TOP count/2 https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+return+number+of+rows&ie=&oe= or split it up by even fewer rows.

Comment: It would be nice if I could return just a list of ItemIDs in a preliminary query, then use that list to make smaller queries. I don't see any built in capability to limit the result data beyond the basic part data, only ways to add on more extended data.

Comment: Do you have access to the SELECT sql, or is it all behind the API?

Comment: The API removes the ability to for queries using raw SQL, for fear of screwing with the Prophet 21 database UI software. I am using c# and .NET, and the proprietary Epicor Database Middleware API, which is pretty crummy.

Comment: API = good times. I don't know how your data is arranged, but you could partition it using UTF-8 like for(I=37;i<48;select where prodName.Startswith(((char)I).ToString()) then put those in a dictionary keyed on the first letter.

Comment: The api is crummy?  Holden, is that you?

Comment: I dont know who Holden is, but the Epicor API is trash, ha. This question is mainly about the way i which C# will sort strings. If i wanted to just return all strings that start with B or b and before, and the strings are of differing lengths. is there a link to a table which shows sorting priority for these ASCII comparison operators? i did try googling this to no avail, thanks.

Comment: Oh yeah, catcher in the rye *facepalm*. Im still having this problem with my database API that the results time out if its over 200 items, because there is no output selection or pagination. just looking for a good strategy to divide up the query in a way that is scalable. thanks!

Comment: would (A > a), would (A > aa) ??? how is value assigned?

Comment: i want to make sure i include every result from the initial query, given a disproportionate amount are just numbers, or start with character A-D. i just want to make several small queries, so that it doesn't matter if there is 300 that all start with A and cause a time out, and collectively they would return the whole list.